# CGAffineTransformMake shifts my object before transforming

Tags: objective-c, animation

I have a button (actually four of them) in a specific position that I want to rotate and translate at the same time, therefore I opted to use CGAffineTransformMake and provide the transformation matrix.

However I noticed that if I want to translate x = -100, for instance, the button will first be instantly shifted x = +200 and then will animate it's transformation to x = -100.

Is there any way to make it translate without this shift to the opposite direction?

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(-1, 0, 0, -1, -100, 0); // Spins 180° and translates

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Show Menu" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.4];
_menuButton1.transform = transform;
[_menuButton1 setAlpha:1.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: First, use the UIView animation block method. Second, are you using AutoLayout in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using that animation method. It is discouraged by Apple after iOS 4.0. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations:context:

The preferred method is...

```
[UIView animateWithDelay:0.0
                duration:2.4
                 options:0
              animations:^() {
                  _menuButton1.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(-1, 0, 0, -1, -100, 0);
                  _menuButton1.alpha = 1.0;
              }
              completion:nil];
```

Will edit my answer when you reply to my comment.

OK, the cause for this shift is that you are trying to translate the view whilst using AutoLayout to constrain it.

I don't know why it causes an issue, but it does.

Your two options for fixing it are...

1. Turn of AutoLayout and then you code will work.
2. Keep AutoLayout enabled and learn how to animate constraints.

For the second option I can recommend the book "iOS6 by Tutorials" by Ray Wenderlich and his team.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-6-by-tutorials

I used this to learn how to do AutoLayout properly.

Comment: Why should I prefer this method? I tried and it shifted the button just like before.
Also, you swapped delay and duration.

Comment: Yes, it will do. Your method is the old animation method. Docs say "Use of this method is discouraged after iOS 4.0". The problem with the shift is probably due to using it with AutoLayout. Like I asked in the comment... are you using AutoLayout in this view?

Comment: Yes, I am using autolayout.

Comment: I disabled the autolayout, which was not needed in this particular nib, and everything is perfect now.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with one of the transforms, let's say translation:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100.0f, 0.0f);
```

And then add rotation to it:

```
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, (float)M_PI_2);
```

And finally set this transform to your view's `transform` property.

Comment: The issue is not that the transform is incorrect. The issue is that the animation is incorrect. You are just creating the same transform in two lines instead of one. I have seen this "shift" before when using an animation like this with AutoLayout enabled. Which is what I suspect the problem is. Just not getting any reply regarding this from the asker.

Comment: You're right, it is an auto-layout issue. I prefer writing multiple transforms like this though, I guess it's a matter of preference. :-)

Comment: Actually, yes, I prefer writing `NSPredicates` using `NSCompoundPredicate` to combine them. Same thing, preference.